# Error making the GitLab Runner work on MacOS?

Tags: git, macos, gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I have issues making a GitLab Runner work on MacOs.

I tried to follow the steps described in GitLab to register a new runner for a certain project. The runner appears in the git list but it has an alert icon saying "New Runner, has not contacted yet". When I push to git, the pipeline fails because the runner does not work.

My config.toml is the following (the url is and token is intentionally covered):

```
[[runners]]
  name = "mac"
  url = "https://*********/"
  id = 7944
  token = "*******************"
  token_obtained_at = 2023-03-13T11:41:22Z
  token_expires_at = 0001-01-01T00:00:00Z
  executor = "shell"
```

the gitlab-runner-err.log has the following:

```
Runtime platform                                  [0;m  arch[0;m=amd64 os[0;m=darwin pid[0;m=****** revision[0;m=****** version[0;m=16.0.1
Starting multi-runner from /Users/************/.gitlab-runner/config.toml...[0;m  builds[0;m=0
[0;33mWARNING: Running in user-mode.                    [0;m 
[0;33mWARNING: Use sudo for system-mode:                [0;m 
[0;33mWARNING: $ sudo gitlab-runner...                  [0;m 
                                                  [0;m 
Configuration loaded                              [0;m  builds[0;m=0
listen_address not defined, metrics & debug endpoints disabled[0;m  builds[0;m=0
[session_server].listen_address not defined, session endpoints disabled[0;m  builds[0;m=0
Initializing executor providers                   [0;m  builds[0;m=0
[31;1mERROR: Checking for jobs... forbidden             [0;m  [31;1mrunner[0;m=****
[31;1mERROR: Checking for jobs... forbidden             [0;m  [31;1mrunner[0;m=****
[31;1mERROR: Checking for jobs... forbidden             [0;m  [31;1mrunner[0;m=****
[31;1mERROR: Runner "https://git.****.**/*****" is unhealthy and will be disabled for 1h0m0s seconds![0;m  [31;1munhealthy_requests[0;m=3 [31;1munhealthy_requests_limit[0;m=3
[0;33mWARNING: [runWait] received stop signal           [0;m  [0;33mbuilds[0;m=0 [0;33mstop-signal[0;m=terminated
[0;33mWARNING: Graceful shutdown not finished properly. To gracefully clean up running plugins please use SIGQUIT (ctrl-\) instead of SIGINT (ctrl-c)[0;m  [0;33mbuilds[0;m=0 [0;33merror[0;m=received stop signal: terminated
[0;33mWARNING: Starting forceful shutdown               [0;m  [0;33mStopSignal[0;m=terminated [0;33mbuilds[0;m=0 [0;33mshutdown-timeout[0;m=30s
All workers stopped.                              [0;m  builds[0;m=0
Shutting down executor providers                  [0;m  builds[0;m=0 shutdown-timeout[0;m=30s
All executor providers shut down.                 [0;m  builds[0;m=0
Can exit now!                                     [0;m  builds[0;m=0
```

Comment: You've either not used the correct URL or you have not used an appropriate/valid token.  "Checking for jobs... forbidden" means the runner is getting a 403 response when trying to reach the URL specified. Did you run `gitlab-runner register` to set the token in the config?

Comment: I did use a correct URL and run gitlab-runner register. I also see the runner appear in the runners section of the CI/CD settings of my repo in git. As I said it says "New Runner, has not contacted yet".